# How to change Label Text color of masterPageitem after selection

Tags: xamarin, navigation, master-detail

I'm new to Xamarin framework and want to create an app using Master-Detail Page
I did simple Master-Detail Navigation page demo from xamarin websit 
[master-detail-page xamarin webise](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/)

only difference is I used ViewCell inside DataTemplate.In ViewCell I have Label
instead of Image.
after clicking on `MasterPageItems` navigation is working fine but now I want to **change the label Text color** also .

```
      <ListView x:Name="listView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" SeparatorVisibility="None" RowHeight="50" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="#1ca7ec" FontSize="18"></Label>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>

void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem; 
        if (item != null)
        {                
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ContactsPage)));
            masterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see you bind the Text of your Label. Why don't you bind the TextColor too ?

Comment: I tried that... but the changes are not  reflecting on master page. It is only binding the Text Color for First time not after selecting the item on master page

Comment: Is your binding mode in the two ways ?
=> TextColor="{Binding TitleColor, Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: No. that is also not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do in this way:

1- in your model you should have a "TextColor" property and a "Selected" property

```
public bool Selected { get; set; }

// I think you should not return "Color" type (for strong MVVM) but, for example, a value that you can convert in XAML with a IValueConverter...
public Color TextColor
{
    get
    {
        if (Selected)
            return Color.Black;
        else
            return Color.Green;
    }
}
```

2- In your XAML you should have something like

```
<ListView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="{Binding TextColor}" FontSize="18"></Label>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

3- and in your ViewModel something like

```
MyModel _selectedItem { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<MyModel> List { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();

public MyModel SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedItem != null)
            _selectedItem.Selected = false;

        _selectedItem = value;

        if (_selectedItem != null)
            _selectedItem.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

When your item in the list is selected , SelectedItem property change and Selected property in your model became True or False, changing the TextColor property (I use PropertyChanged.Fody for INPC).

Hope this help
You can find the repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/acaliaro/TestSelectedItemInListView)

Instead of use a TextColor Property in your Model, I think you can also use only Selected property and an IValueConverter that convert Selected property to a color

Comment: Changed the repo. Now I Use a IValueConverter to change Selected to a Color

Comment: Tried above code also,but still same problem . Title color not changing From green to black after clicking on it .

Comment: Very strange. Have you download the repo?

Comment: Yes I did.  But i used the repo as reference and made some changes in my code.

Comment: The repo should work, I have tested it in Android and iOS. Maybe something in your changes is wrong. If you use Xamarin Studio take a look to Application Output TAB, maybe some warnings there.

Comment: There are no warnings.I think its because of Master page. I'm  not able to change the properties of label once master page is initialized. BTW there is no Problem with Repo its working.

Comment: when I have 2 minutes I try to check with MasterDetail

Comment: Ok, tested with MasterDetail page. No problems for me. Updated repo on github. Take a look

Comment: actually the main reason for label TextColor is I have an event handler on ListView ItemSelected   which  Navigates to the selected  page (label).If I remove the handler the Label color changes after clicking.but if the handler is there then its not working.

Comment: try to remove this line             masterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;

Comment: ok its working but i dont want the background color for selected item in ListView

Comment: Try to implement what have you done for TextColor also for Background color. The problem is that you set SelectedItem to null...

Comment: Ok I will try...thanx

Comment: Is it possible to write a code without using Fody/PropertyChanged ?

Comment: yes you have to write you propertychanged https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/

Comment: I did the exact same thing and its working in Masterdetail demo app. but in  another app its not working . the code in TestSelectedItemInListViewViewModel is  "PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedItem"));"  and  In MasterPageItem is "PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Clr"));"     the problem is the get
    {
        if (Selected)
            return Color.Black;
        else
            return Color.Green;
    }      --these lines not getting executed